# Is there a method to estimate the distribution of error term in linear model?

Tags: estimation, linear-model, density-estimation

Consider the linear model where $A$ is not known
$$
y = Ax + \epsilon
$$
where we want to estimate the distribution $\epsilon$ from a set of samples. To prevent over-fitting, we want to impose some smooth constraints on the PDF of $\epsilon.$ Then we want to maximise
$$
l = \sum_i \log f(y_i-Ax_i)
$$
over all coefficients $A$ and all PDF $f$ in a class $\mathcal F.$

Does anyone know any existing result on this? A reference would be very helpful.

Comment: Could you please explain how this question is not asking about *any* linear model?